# I am using BFAST to do a time series analysis of LST and I am getting NaN errors

Tags: raster, r, remote-sensing, rasterstack, bfast

This is the blog post I refer to,  https://philippgaertner.github.io/2018/04/bfast-preparation/, and the author's code is as follows:

`# NDVI data`

`data(tura)`

`selected_pixel <- 90`   represents a random selection of 90 pixels?

`# number of valid values in TS`

`nbr.NA <- sum(!is.na( !as.vector(tura[selected_pixel])))`

`##116L`

`# create a regular time series object by combining data and dateinformation`

`(s <- bfastts(as.vector(tura[selected_pixel]), dates, type = c("irregular")))`

`##Time-Series [1:10530] from 1984n to 2013: NA NA 7839 NA 3498…`

The picture below is `tura`
[image]

I replaced the `tura` with `LST` (Land Surface Temperature) data, `LST`is the MOD11A1 of September 2019 to September 2019, which is from ROI. I composed a RasterStack.
[image]

`nbr.NA <- sum(!is.na( !as.vector(LST[selected_pixel])))`. The result obtained is `0L`.

`(s1 <- bfastts(as.vector(LST[selected_pixel]), dates1, type = c("irregular")))` shown as:
The following figure is  `LST`
Time Series:

```
Start = c(2019, 244) 
End = c(2019, 273) 
Frequency = 365 
 [1] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
[21] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Why is it all NAN?

Comment: I had the same issue when I used MODIS  LST data but with BFAST Monitor. At first I thought it was because of the length of my ts so I used Landsat's 5 and 8 LST. But no, the same result, the outputs was full of NaN.

Comment: Hi Nikos, thank you for your prompt reply, I am thinking about the dataset, because the dataset in the reference blog is 'tura', in 'tura[selected_pixel]' can get NA or numerical value, but when I use LST dataset,  'LST [selected_pixel]' is getting NaN, I guess this may be the cause of the error.But I don't find a solution in Google.

Comment: Hard to tell without your data. What's `LST`? What's `LST[selected_pixel]`? What's `as.vector(LST[selected_pixel])`? Does it all look okay going into `bfastts`?

Comment: As @Spacedman correctly pointed out, you should explain in more detail what is LST, what `LST [selected pixel]` does etc. In the meantime, if you find a solution please post it here. I remember, I posted a similar question on GitHub, but for BFAST Monitor, as I said, but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: LST refers to MOD11A1 for 30 days in September 2019,I composite them(LST) into a RasterStack,This is my blog post： https://philippgaertner.github.io/2018/04/bfast-preparation/. 
There is a behavior in the code posted by the author, ` selected_pixel <- 90`, 
The data he uses is tura, I will replace it with LST, `tura[selected_pixel]` (I think he chose 90 pixels of the RasterStack)
`tura[selected_pixel]`returns NA or a numeric value. 
but I replace tura with LST, `LST[selected_pixel]` Returns NaN. Thank you for your reply, I will go to github to find your question.

Answer (score 0):

This object name is misleading. The next line counts the number that **ARE** not NA, the "number of valid values" not the number of NA:

```
# number of valid values in TS
nbr.NA <- sum(!is.na( !as.vector(tura[selected_pixel])))
```

As a test, consider a vector with four values and an NA:

```
> Z = c(1,2,3,4,NA)
> sum(!is.na(!as.vector(Z)))
[1] 4
```

You get zero for pixel 90, which means every layer of pixel 90 is NA, so you will get `NaN` once R tries to compute with all `NA`s.

Try another pixel for a sample. And I don't know why the test isnt:

```
nbr.NA = sum(is.na(LST[selected_pixel]))
```

or why the comment is the wrong way round.

Comment: Great thanks. Really appreciate your help.I changed `selected_pixel <- 90` to `selected_pixel <- 90000`, `(s1 <- bfastts(as.vector(LST[selected_pixel]), dates1, type = c("irregular")))` .No more NaN.My guess is that there are too many NA values ​​in my LST dataset.

Comment: Your stack is 555x538, so pixel 90 will be in the top left corner, and its not uncommon for data to have all NA areas round the edges where its been masked to a rectangle. If you want a pixel in the middle go for `selected_pixel = round(555*538/2)`

Comment: Much appreciated! `selected_pixel = round(555*538/2)` is good advice!